# UIAutomatorViewer unable to detect page elements

Tags: selenium, xpath, appium, android-uiautomator

I am trying to autoamte the eBay mobile native app using Selenium Appium.I am able to retrieve the page elements of all the pages however for the Sign In page I am not. I am getting error message in both UIAutomator and Appium Inspector 1.6.5 keeps searching with no response. I would like to know if the issue is with the eBay page or is there any other alternative ways to find the locators.
Steps to reproduce:
1. Search any object in ebay -> go to details page -> Click on watch

[CaptureImage Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROA75.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This issue occur if your appium server is on OR APP in mobile or emulator, now again open the app and navigate to screen you wanted. try this time

OR

stop your server and close this uiautomatorviwer and again open uiautomatorviwer. Your will not get the error this time.

another way to locate element is:-

Use below code :-

```
System.out.println("source : "+ driver.getPageSource());
```

`driver.getPageSource()` will return you the XML of screen.
Now you can construct an xpath on your element.

Use below link to beautify your xml

http://xmlbeautifier.com/

Use below code to validate your xpath

https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Hope it will help you :)